# How do I get a vocabulary from columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a rather large dataset stored in a dataframe. So large , in fact, that sorting through the dataset to generate an example dataset has caused my text editor to crash. Because of this, I am providing links to the datasets I'm using:

https://github.com/moonman239/Capstone-project/blob/master/data.zip

For planning purposes, I need to retrieve the vocabulary of words from the question,article_title and paragraph_context columns.

However, it appears that in the process of splitting and combining the columns, I have inadvertently created some words by mashing together two words end-to-end (e.g: "raised" and "in" become "raisedin" catalans")

```
### Loading JSON datasets

import json
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\W+')
def readFile(filename):
  with open(filename) as file:
    fields = []
    JSON = json.loads(file.read())
    for article in JSON["data"]:
      articleTitle = article["title"]
      for paragraph in article["paragraphs"]:
        paragraphContext = paragraph["context"]
        for qas in paragraph["qas"]:
          question = qas["question"]
          for answer in qas["answers"]:
            fields.append({"question":question,"answer_text":answer["text"],"answer_start":answer["answer_start"],"paragraph_context":paragraphContext,"article_title":articleTitle})
  fields = pd.DataFrame(fields)
  fields["question"] = fields["question"].str.replace(regex," ")
  assert not (fields["question"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  fields["paragraph_context"] = fields["paragraph_context"].str.replace(regex," ")
  fields["answer_text"] = fields["answer_text"].str.replace(regex," ")
  assert not (fields["answer_text"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  fields["article_title"] = fields["article_title"].str.replace("_"," ")
  assert not (fields["article_title"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  return fields
# Load training dataset.
trainingData = readFile("train-v1.1.json")

# Vocabulary functions
def vocabulary():
  data_frame = trainingData
  data_frame = data_frame.astype("str")
  text_split = pd.concat((data_frame["question"],data_frame["paragraph_context"],data_frame["article_title"]),ignore_index=True)
  text_split = text_split.str.split()
  words = set()
  text_split.apply(words.update)
  return words
def vocabularySize():
  return len(vocabulary())
```

**Alternate code that also fails:**

```
def vocabulary():
  data_frame = trainingData
  data_frame = data_frame.astype("str")
  concat = data_frame["question"].str.cat(sep=" ",others=[data_frame["paragraph_context"],data_frame["article_title"]])
  concat = concat.str.split(" ")
  words = set()
  concat.apply(words.update)
  print(words)
  assert "raisedin" not in words
  return words
```

Comment: Please try to provide a **minimal**, reproducible, complete example.  We don't have access to your to your good drive, so that chunk of code is not useful.  We don't have access to the json data, so that is not useful either.  Etc.

Comment: @James: Noted. I have uploaded an MCVE and a link to one of my datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my approach to the problem:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.read_json('train-v1.1.json')

words = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    #title
    words.append(json_normalize(df['data'][idx])['title'].str.replace("_"," ").to_string(index = False))
    #paragraph context
    words.append(json_normalize(df['data'][idx], record_path = 'paragraphs')['context'].to_string(index = False))
    #question
    words.append(json_normalize(df['data'][idx], record_path = ['paragraphs', 'qas'])['question'].to_string(index = False))


vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
count = vectorizer.fit_transform(words)
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

sklearn has a function that does literally what you want to do, get all the individual words for a set of data. In order to use this we need to put all the data into 1 list or series.

How we accomplish creation of the list is by first reading in the file. I noticed that there are many json files embedded within, so next we are going to loop over all the different jsons and pull the data we want, then add it to a list called words.

How we pull the info we need is from the following:

```
json_normalize(df['data'][idx], record_path = ['paragraphs', 'qas'])['question'].to_string(index = False)
```

We look at the data column of our df which contains the individual jsons. The we navigate through the json until we are at the point we want to be through record_path. Next we take the column we want, convert it all to strings, then append the new list to our master word list. We do that for all the different json files.

If you want to perform any more string manipulation (such as removing "_" for " ") you can do it in the for loop or with the master words list. I only did it for the titles in my case.

Finally we are going to add up the words. We create a CountVectorizer called vectorizer, we fit and transform our list. Finally we can investigate our CountVectorizer through the get_feature_names() function to see every word. Note, if there are spelling mistakes in the text they will also be there.

**EDIT**:

You can use the code below to search for words and see where they are. Change the values in checking to whatever you want.

```
df = pd.read_json('train-v1.1.json')

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
checking = ['raisedin']

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    title = []
    para = []
    quest = []

    getTitle = json_normalize(df['data'][idx])['title'].str.replace("_"," ")
    getPara = json_normalize(df['data'][idx], record_path = 'paragraphs')['context']
    getQuest = json_normalize(df['data'][idx], record_path = ['paragraphs', 'qas'])['question']

    title.append(getTitle.str.replace("_"," ").to_string(index = False))
    para.append(getPara.to_string(index = False))
    quest.append(getQuest.to_string(index = False))

    for word in checking:
        for allwords in [getTitle, getPara, getQuest]:
            count = vectorizer.fit_transform(allwords)
            test = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
            if word in test:
                print(getTitle)
                print(f"{word} is in: " +  allwords.loc[allwords.str.contains(word)])

0    Poultry
Name: title, dtype: object
93    raisedin is in: How long does it take for an broiler raisedin...
Name: question, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That didn't solve the problem, but I now have a better idea where the problem is - and it must be before the vocabulary function.

Comment: So I did some more digging for you, and its not your code, its the text. For example, question 93 of the json titled Poultry contains the word 'raisedin', and thats where your getting it from. It states "How long does it take for an broiler raisedin...". You just have to be cognizant of the fact that with real data spelling mistakes, and missed spaces happen.